# pageLoadTimeout & implcitlyWait -Wrong Setup?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**I’m struggling to figure out whether my ‘wait setups’ are correctly coded, please can someone advise?**

1. For example if I run let’s say TestX , if I purposely input the incorrect xpath locator inside a basic click method
2. Referring to the code highlighted below my test should wait 10Seconds even if I embed a 10seconds Explicit timeout within my test method if the test and method cannot find the relevant element which its trying to look for and click.
3. The problem im facing is that my tests seem to throw an error / unable to locate element exception before the 10secoind duration
4. If I comment out the window.maximize code, I can identify that the code works which is housed inside the Base_page class.
5. Can someone advise from their experience whether my class and wait code setup is correct?

**Many thanks for your help**

[image]

Comment: @Xwris Stoixeia can you advise on this question? thanks again

Comment: Change `driver.manage()` to `this.driver.manage()`. You  modified local constructor variable instead of `this.driver` which is an instance variable and probably used further on.